# default 'docker run' options?

Tags: docker

I am running virtualbox images inside docker containers and this requires launching docker with either

```
docker run -i -t --device=/dev/vboxdrv fommil/freeslick:base
```

or

```
docker run -i -t --privileged=true fommil/freeslick:base
```

Obviously, the former is preferable, but I have no control over the way the target script launches the docker instance (it is managed by a third party) other than turning on/off privileged mode.

Is there a way to set system defaults for `docker run` such that all images launched on a Linux boxen will use `--device=/dev/vboxdrv`?

Comment: Unfortunately docker-compose doesn't [support every `docker run` flag](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/754) yet, but when it does it will be a good solution for your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `--device` is an ["operator exclusive option"](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#operator-exclusive-options) it can only be specified at the invocation of the `docker run` command. So no, there is no way to default that option.